# Sending an email via gmail using Codeigniter and WAMP

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, wamp

```
            $config = Array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
            'smtp_port' => 465,
            'smtp_user' => 'xxx',
            'smtp_pass' => 'xxx',
            'mailtype'  => 'html', 
            'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
        );
        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

        $this->email->from('me@gmail.com','me');
        $this->email->to($this->input->post('email'));
        $this->email->subject("Confirm your account.");
        
        $message = '<p>Thank you for signing up!</p>';
        $message .= '<p><a href="';
        $message .= base_url();
        $message .= 'main/register_user';
        $message .= $key;
        $message .= '">Click here!</a>to sign up</p>';
        $this->email->message($message);
```

I'm following some Codeigniter tutorials from phpacademy on youtube. One of the tutorials has you email a unique key to a user so they can register. I'm attempting to send via a gmail account, using other questions and CI forums I've gotten to the code above, but I get the following errors:

> Message: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to >ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget >to enable it when you configured PHP?)
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php

--

> Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php

--

> Message: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php

I'm lost as to the exact steps I need to take to set this up properly. Also, when I move this from local to an actual webhost will it still properly work with my gmail?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you have mod_ssl active on apache server

Comment: Wow. I feel like a complete idiot. I'm over here yelling at my ini file scaring my cat.

This solved everything. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

You try to connect over SSL then you should activate the OpenSSL module `php_openssl.dll` in your **php.ini**.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have OpenSSL enabled now and it works.

Comment: No worries. Next time you think about :D

Answer (score 1):

Code be like this:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail<br/>
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';<br/>
$mail->Port = 587;
```

Apart from this, configure your apache and wamp like this:

1. Uncomment `extension=php_openssl.dll` in php.ini file
2. Check the `ssl_module` active in apache modules